# Correct path in MediaWiki

Tags: php, path, mediawiki, wiki

I have a problem with my **MediaWiki** (www.sfb-higher-invariants.de).

- The login is connected via a **Single-Sign-On** of the University of Regensburg.
  By **logging in, there is a redirect to a specific site**.
- After a correct login there is another redirect back to the Wiki.
- When not being logged in, the Wiki is on the server www-cgi.
- After logging into it the server changes (to a secure server).

My Problem:
- If I set the **$wgScriptPaht** to **www-cgi** image uploads are working and the css is loaded.

- But the redirect to the secure server does not work properly.
- If I set no path, the redirect works, but the other two things fail.
  The secure server is https.
- Where do I get the path, which the Wiki sets automatically? And how can I work around this mess?

PS: There is no other way for the sign in because of security reasons of the university... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server name can be overridden with `$wgServer`, if I understand your question correctly, this is the parameter you are looking for.

If you need to, you can set both upload path a and style path separately, using `$wgUploadPath` and `$wgStylePath`, even though I can't figure out why that would be necessary.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your fast answer. But that's not the problem. After signing into the MediaWiki, the Wiki itself sets a new server. But by doing this, it does not recognize that it is on https://
Another problem is by not setting those paths: nothings happens.

Comment: Ok, then I didn't properly understand your question. When redirected back from `Special:Login`, do you end up on another domain, or just another protocol?

Comment: I end up on another domain and another protocol. So by changing the $wgServer it crashes. Also, the Wiki does not set the right protocol after Special:Login.
I am using http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:QISSingleSignOn this SSO for my login. But it seems not to be the problem.